# Retrieving nodes with tag in XDocument

Tags: xml, linq, soap

I'm connecting to a SOAP service and writing the response from that service to an XDocument. The XDocument contains a bunch of different nodes and I want to extract the nodes with the tag "ConfigurationId". Sometimes there is only one node with this tag, and sometimes there are more at different levels. Line 1 in the code below gets the response, line 2 serializes the response to an XDocument and line 3 gets the descendants with the tag. When I run it I get the message in the console window below. When I print the "result" variable, it prints the entire XDocument as it should be, so something fails in line 3. Any idea why?

```
GetResponse response = myClient.getConfigNumbersAsync(messageContextType, configurationRequestType).Result;

var result = XMLHandler.Serialize(response);

var query = from c in result.Descendants("ConfigurationId") select c;

Console.WriteLine(query);
```

[image]

Comment: You results query is an array of XElement which you cannot print.  It is not a string.  Try following : string query = string.Join(",", result.Descendants("ConfigurationId").Select(x => x.ToString()));

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Comment: New question: What if I want to create a List<XElement> from the elements in the XDocument result with the tag "ConfigurationId", how could I do that?

Comment: List<XElement> configurationIds = result.Descendants("ConfigurationId").ToList();